# Does greater mage hand satisfy the requirement to access the arcane trickster prestige class?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, prestige-class

My character is a spellthief and it has no access to level 0 spells. I'd like to get some levels as an Arcane Trickster, but I only have access to Greater Mage Hand, could it be enough to qualify for the prestige class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, no, *mage hand* and *greater mage hand* are separate spells and knowing *greater mage hand* doesn’t count as knowing *mage hand*. You cannot qualify for arcane trickster with *greater mage hand*.

But the only reason that’s true is because arcane trickster was written before *greater mage hand* existed. Ask your DM—I’d be surprised if they had a problem with it.

But note that arcane trickster isn’t a very good choice for a spellthief—you already get sneak attack, which is the main advantage of arcane trickster, and arcane trickster won’t do anything for your spell stealing. Ranged legerdemain is cool and all, but you can do much more with spellthief than you can with arcane trickster.

Comment: thank you, I would like to know more about the alternatives for the spellthief you aformentioned. I know I should open a different thread, but could you give me some ideas for it?

Comment: @Verdict00 Yeah, that would be a separate question, and you would need to give a lot more detail on what exactly you were looking for from the character, but if you’re thinking of multiclassing, you’ll want Master Spellthief from *Complete Scoundrel*. It’s not perfect, but it helps you not lose too much spell-thieving when you take other classes (like arcane trickster). Unseen seer is a common choice for skilled, trickstery arcanists—it’s the magical spy class—and so that could be OK. But really, spellthieves usually stay spellthieves. Borrow spells from your allies; it helps a lot.